# Backreference in Web API routes

Tags: regex, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have a numbering scheme for orders in my application where the order number is composed of the customer number and a counter. I would like to have a route defined for an action where this restriction is enforced.

If a customer has the customer number ABCD1234 and wants to request the status of the first order, it would need to do a GET-request to the URL:

`/api/customers/ABCD1234/orders/ABCD1234-001/status`

But a GET-request to the url

`/api/customers/ABCD1234/orders/WXYZ9876-023/status`

should fail, because the customer number is not part of the order number. Preferably a route pattern like this:

```
[Route("/api/customers/{customerNumber:regex(^([A-Z]{4}\\d{4})$)}/orders/{orderNumber:regex(^\\1\-\\d{3})$}/status")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetStatus(string customerNumber, string orderNumber)
```

Is there a way to enforce this?

Comment: Note you have a typo - `[A-Z]{4]` must be `[A-Z]{4}`.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question.

Comment: Backreferences do not work across different regexes, only within one pattern.

Comment: I know. That is why I posted this question.